# Validating specific date format in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I need to verify whether the dates in my Excel table are in the correct format, which is `yyyy/mm/dd`, so any other formats like `mm/dd/yyyy` would be incorrect.

I am using this formula:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(TEXT(W2,"yyyy/mm/dd")))),"valid date","invalid date"
```

While the formula did pick up cells that did not contain a date, it failed to pick up cells that had dates in the wrong format like `mm/dd/yyyy`.  What am I missing from my formula?  Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Kev

Comment: A true date is a number, specifically the number of days since 1/1/1900.  You can format this number any way you want.  There is no way via formula that will allow you to test the format of a cell.  The best method is to format the cells prior to entering the date and Excel will then take any valid date and display it in the format you choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check the format of a cell, put this User Defined Function in a standard module:

```
Public Function FormatChecker(r As Range) As String
    FormatChecker = r(1).NumberFormat
End Function
```

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=FormatChecker(A1)
```

and copy down.  In **C1** enter:

```
=IF(AND(LEFT(B1,4)="yyyy",MID(B1,6,2)="mm",RIGHT(B1,2)="dd"),"Good","Bad")
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

If you change the format of a column **A** cell, you will also need to refresh its contents to re-calculate column **B**.  Use:  <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: @user9403589 you thank him by clicking the check mark by the answer to mark it as the correct answer.