# Check Date Formula

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I want to check if the format of a cell (16/12/2022) is correct.

What I thought is:

```
=IF(AND(LEFT(RIGHT(E23;3);1)="/";RIGHT(LEFT(E23;5);1)="/");0;1)
```

but it does not give me what I want. It always gives me back "1" even when the format is correct!

Comment: Will the months and days have leading zeros for single digits?

Comment: Yes they will follow the structure 02/08/2022

Answer (score 0):

A small error in your counting:

> RIGHT(LEFT(E23;5);1) = 2 from the 12

the second "/" is at the 6th character

Also, this method is probably a bit more foolproof:
[How to check date format in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428061/how-to-check-date-format-in-excel)
Or if you want to use a little bit of vba:
[Using a UDF to get the right format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48956375/19353309)